# Intelj Maven Module Project Packages Icon is gray

Tags: intellij-idea

I was using the Intelj 2016.2.1 and updated to 2016.3.3, then re-import my maven module project, But java packages does not have the proper package icon (yellow border icon) how can i get the proper icons for java packages
https://www.jetbrains.com/help/idea/2016.3/symbols.html

[image: Screenshot after Import the maven module project] [image: pacakage icon]

Answer (score 0):

This is a new icons. No way to choose old icons as i know.